# Jibx - how to unmarshal/marshal tag with value and attribute?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jibx, oxm

```
<stateData>
   <MyTag name="voltage">12</Mytag>
   <MyTag name="Fuel">72</Mytag>
</stateData>
```

Sorry Guys, I did not meant to be lazy. Ok Here is the question: I have xml structure with above block of xml which some tags has both value and attribute in tag notation( MyTag has value of 12 and has an attribute name). using Jibx how I can create binding schema for such case. Obviously for xml tags with only value or with attributes without tag value is normal, but when you have both of them I don't know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: C'mon Gord, we're gonna need a little more than this :)

Comment: People that are too lazy to write a complete question do not deserve an answer. Voting for this question to be closed.

Comment: So... Now that this appears to be a real question, and one I was going to ask, let's answer it :-) Adding a bounty...

Answer (score 3):

Use `<value/>` element twice in your binding. Once with `attribute` and once with `text` styles.

For example - to bind the following `StateData` class to the XML you want...

```
public class StateData {
  String name;
  String value;
}
```

...use the binding below:

```
<binding>
  <mapping name="stateData" class="StateData">
    <structure name="MyTag">
      <value style="attribute" name="name" field="name"/>
      <value style="text" field="value"/>
    </structure>
  </mapping>
</binding>
```